# Is is possible to reduce two separate query to only one in Elastic Search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-optimization

I have ElasticSearch data offers with the following structure:

```
{   
   {
        "id": "123",
        "tariffId": "15477",       
        "tariffFamilyId": "555",
        "characteristics": "xxx"
    },
    {
        "id": "124",
        "tariffId": "15478",       
        "tariffFamilyId": "777",
        "characteristics": "yyy"
    },
    {
        "id": "351",
        "tariffId": "25271",       
        "tariffFamilyId": "555",
        "characteristics": "zzz"
    }
}
```

I need to find all offers with `tariffFamilyId` of a certain `tariffId`. As an initial argument, I know only `tariffId` and do not know `tariffFamilyId` (I need to detect it). Normally it means the two separate requests to Elastic Search should be made:

1. first request - find `tariffFamilyId` by `tariffId`.
2. second request - find offers with that `tariffFamilyId`.

For example for `tariffId=15477`, we get `tariffFamilyId=555`. So for this family, there will be two offers with id `123` and `351`.

The question - is it possible to somehow make only one request to Elastic search, not two?

P.S. This is for Java implementation.

Comment: Loosely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415390/combine-output-of-a-a-first-filter-as-input-of-a-second-filter/60516043#60516043 -- long story short, no.